# when I click to yes the id send to the method but axios post not working?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

when I click to yes the id send to the method but axios post not working ?

```
enter <button type="button"  onClick={() => { window.confirm( 'you want to delete this item ?', ) && this.delete(invItem.id) }} class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>

e// delete =(e,id)=>{axios.post("http://localhost:8081/api/delete_user/"+id); window.location.reload(true); }
```

`@PostMapping("/delete_user/{id}") public void del_user(@PathVariable int id) {     this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from users  where id = ?",id);     }`

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting id into your method `this.delete(invItem.id)`? It would be good if you share the error that you got.

Comment: yes ,I saw it in console.log(id)

Comment: Can you update how you are making `axios` call for delete? You said "axios post is not working" and can you check are you getting any errors on console or backend side?

Comment: the error in delete(e,if) I change it by delete(id) ,   e  is for event

Answer (score -2):

you need to change parameters of method
delete =(e,id)=>{...}   to  delete=(id)=>{...}
( e means event) it is the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).